# how to group TR with same class?

Tags: jquery, grouping

I have a table structure. I want to take all the TR having same content in first child TD together and add TR before the group. So, I am trying to group TR with same content.

**My structure is**

```
    <tbody>
         <tr>
              <td class="groupBy">www.bing.com</td>
              <td>2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
              <td class="groupBy">www.google.com</td>
              <td>5</td>
         </tr>
          <tr>
              <td class="groupBy">www.bing.com</td>
              <td>2</td>
         </tr>
          <tr>
              <td class="groupBy">www.yahoo.com</td>
              <td>8</td>
         </tr>
          <tr>
              <td class="groupBy">www.google.com</td>
              <td>8</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
              <td class="groupBy">www.bing.com</td>
              <td>2</td>
         </tr>
    </tbody>
```

**and I want below output after jquery**

```
    <tbody> 
            <tr>
                <p>www.bing.com</p>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                  <td class="groupBy">www.bing.com</td>
                  <td>2</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                  <td class="groupBy">www.bing.com</td>
                  <td>2</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                  <td class="groupBy">www.bing.com</td>
                  <td>2</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <p>www.google.com</p>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                  <td class="groupBy">www.google.com</td>
                  <td>5</td>
             </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td class="groupBy">www.google.com</td>
                  <td>5</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <p>www.yahoo.com</p>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td class="groupBy">www.yahoo.com</td>
                  <td>8</td>
             </tr>
</tbody>
```

Can someone please help me to sort out this?

Comment: Why doing this with tables? manipulating tables is a mess! Your HTML is invalid and wont display correctly you cant throw a `<p>` inside `<tr>`. That's invalid and wont work on some browsers you can never tell how is it gonna be displayed. You are doing something wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have described is sorting the elements not grouping them, here is a dirty solution:

```
var arr = [], s = [];

$('tr').sort(function(a, b){
   return $(a).text() > $(b).text(); 
}).each(function(i, v){
    var t = $('td:first', v).text();
    if ( arr.indexOf(t) === -1) {
       arr.push(t);
       s.push(v);
    }
}).appendTo('tbody').filter(s).before(function(){
    return '<tr class="header"><td><p>' +  $('td:first', this).text() +  '</p></td></tr>';
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SD8at/

Comment: Hey thanks a lot... I was looking for this solution...